# How can I set an Image.Source from a StorageFile without losing quality?

Tags: c#, uwp

[Here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/storagefile/convert-storagefile-to-a-bitmapimage-in-universal-windows-apps/) is a way that I found and it works, but if my image becomes bigger than the values here it loses quality. My image also doesn't have a fixed size, so I would prefer to get it with the original quality.

Comment: It's true, that one probably can guess what you are doing from this link, but this question will be useless should the link go stale. Could you please do a better job explaining you problem and attempted solution **inside your question** please?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
    myImage.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Leaving out height and width will get me the full image!